# Downgrading hostapd didn't help!

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, downgrade

I was searching through the forums to find a solution for the ap-hotspot error - the one that hangs at ***Starting wireless hotspot...*** By now I've tried several solutions including downgrading hostapd and restarting the wifi drivers, but without any luck.

This happend after I upgraded to Xubuntu 14.04 from 13.10 in which it worked quite fine. So I am sure the wifi usb adapter that I'm using supports hotspot creation.

The hostpad.log file:

```
Configuration file: /etc/ap-hotspot.conf
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
```

Comment: see here to resolve your problem https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpa/+bug/1289047